# How do I add git to directory and then commit to existing git project

Tags: git, github

Yes I went about it backwards and searched for hours with no luck. Here is what I did.

On our local server 2 of us are working on different dirs A and B.  We have a remote git repository with master, develop, develop2, develop3.  All branches are in sync with master.

dirA has git develop branch and all commits pushed

dirB was copied from dirA with files only and no git

I made changes to dirB (I have run the command git init on dirB) and need to push them to develop2

My question is will I have to

- delete files in dirB
- fetch master
- checkout branch develop2
- copy changes back to dirB and commit?

Is there and easier way?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the process.  Here is a link. Hope it helps.

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line